# <spring:message> in Spring for .NET - referencing IMessageSource inside xml config

Tags: c#, localization, spring.net

Is there way in Spring for .NET how to use translated message from an `IMessageSource` as constructor argument for other object in the xml application context file? Something like `<spring:message>` in Java. My example:

```xml
<!-- my message source -->
<object name="messageSource" type="MyMessageSource"></object>
<object type="MyLocalizedObject">
  <!-- my object, where I need to pass tranlated message into the argument: -->
  <constructor-arg name="localizedTitle" value=">{translated title.key}<"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it with an expression:

```xml
<object name="messageSource" type="MyMessageSource"></object>
<object type="q9257449_springmessage.MyClass, q9257449_springmessage">
  <constructor-arg name="localizedTitle" 
                   expression="@(messageSource).GetMessage('HelloMessage', 'mr.', 'Anderson')" />
</object>
```

There might be a better way to achieve this, but in the meantime this should get you going.

Comment: Another approach suggested [in the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/quickstarts.html#qs-appcontext-messagesource) is to let the object implement `IInitializingObject` and use `IApplicationContext` inside an `AfterPropertiesSet` callback to set the objects's culture aware properties. But this would require changes to your codebase.

Comment: You could also implement your own [`IVariableSource`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-variablesource), so that you can do `<constructor-arg name="localizedTitle" value="${HelloMessage}" />` but that would not allow you to use message parameters.